# Showsnackbar in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, snackbar

I don't want to call show SnackBar on every single Page. Is there any way to call snack bar globally only once? I used this But it shows context error.

```
ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
```

Comment: You can use [getx](https://pub.dev/packages/get)  package to call the snackbar globally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must write this method in a separate file. Call it where you need it, and it is necessary to pass the current class **context**.

```
showAlert(BuildContext context) {
 ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
     const SnackBar(
      content: Text("Type Your message here..."),
    ),
  );
}
```